# Definition of multiplicity in a collision experiment

Tags: collision, definition

How is multiplicity defined in a collision experiment? Is it simply the number of particles that reach the detectors, or is there some cut in pseudorapidity/transverse momentum? (as there is when talking about a specific type of particle, e.g. baryons or charged)

Answer (score 0):

Charged multiplicity  is defined as the  total number of charged particles coming out of an interaction, and it is easier to study. Total multiplicity needs detectors for neutral particles and gamma rays. Multiplicity  can be expressed as a function of some  interesting variable, depending on the [experiment's aims.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.5104)

> Measurements are presented from proton-proton collisions at centre-of-mass energies of sqrt(s) = 0.9, 2.36 and 7 TeV recorded with the ATLAS detector at the LHC. Events were collected using a single-arm minimum-bias trigger. The charged-particle multiplicity, its dependence on transverse momentum and pseudorapidity and the relationship between the mean transverse momentum and charged-particle multiplicity are measured. Measurements in different regions of phase-space are shown, providing diffraction-reduced measurements as well as more inclusive ones. The observed distributions are corrected to well-defined phase-space regions, using model-independent corrections. The results are compared to each other and to various Monte Carlo models,